# Why some SPARQL queries lack FROM keyword?

Tags: sparql

I am using this client 
http://yasgui.laurensrietveld.nl
and I hope to query bioportal http://bioportal.bioontology.org

Most of my prior queries had a PREFIX and no FROM part. Can I move any FROM URL into PREFIX?

Using YASGUI client, what is the difference between FROM and the Endpoint field?

Can I rewrite any query with a from statement into a query that does not have it?

I am not able to list for example details of Human Phenotype Ontology concept id: HP:0000023 because I am not sure what to put into FROM or if to use it at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of terms and mechanisms here. Let's go over them one by one.

First of all, a `PREFIX` clause is simply a declaration of a syntax shortcut, for use within your query. So this line:

```
PREFIX ex: <http://example.org/>
```

says that the string `ex:` is a shortcut for the string `http://example.org/`. If you have this prefix declared at the start of your query, you can use `ex:someUrl` (instead of `<http://example.org/someUrl>`) in other places in your query. It's simply there to make queries easier to read and write, but apart from that it has no influence on the meaning of your query.

A *SPARQL endpoint* is another term for a web service that can answer SPARQL queries.

The `FROM` clause of a SPARQL query determines the *dataset* (or more precisely, the *default graph*, which is part of the dataset) over which the query is executed. Any SPARQL endpoint may contain several graphs, each identified by a URI (so-called *named graphs*). A collection of such graph together is a dataset. If you don't specify a `FROM` clause (and perhaps also one or more `FROM NAMED` clauses), the dataset queried is simply whatever default dataset the endpoint chooses.

So, what this mean for your specific questions?

> Most of my prior queries had a PREFIX and no FROM part. Can I move any FROM URL into PREFIX?

As you can see from the above explanation, that would make no sense. They are different mechanisms, for different purposes, that just both happen to use URIs.

> Using YASGUI client, what is the difference between FROM and the Endpoint field?

The endpoint field defines which service YASGUI needs to send the query to. The `FROM` clause tells the endpoint what dataset you want to query.

> Can I rewrite any query with a from statement into a query that does not have it?

Not generally, no. The absence of a `FROM` clause means that the endpoint executes the query over its default dataset. Depending on how that endpoint is configured, this may mean that you either get a lot more results (namely not just from the one dataset you want, but from a lot of others) or none at all (in case the dataset you wanted to query is not part of the endpoint's default dataset).